# Tuning Mesh drumheads

Tags: tuning, acoustic-drumset

I fitted my drumset with Remo Silent Stroke heads for home practice convenience. However I cannot seem to be able to 'tune' the heads appropriately.

I can't get enough sound out of them when tuning them by feel -- like when tunning 'regular" heads -- to be able to make up if they are tune right. And if they are  very, very tight, the volume gets just a tiny louder and they become very bouncy and

I try using tune bot, but I cannot register any frequencies.

Does any one has advice or tuning tricks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called "silent" for a reason! You should not expect to hear much more than the sticking when using these heads.

Tuning, in my experience, will only serve two purposes: adjusting the bounce (feel/responsiveness), and helping triggers accurately register.

It has been suggested that the best way to affect the pitch (faint though be) is to adjust the resonant head.

Comment: +1 I tuned my mesh heads entirely for feel. You could add that to change the tone you want to tune the resonator head.

Answer (score 0):

I found that to get "more" sound out of the mesh head, is to "trap" the sound by covering areas of the head with painters tape, and you can control the level of volume and tone: The more of the head that is covered the more volume and tone the emit.

Comment: I think what you mean by “trap” the sound is, you give the head some way to actually move a bit of air and thus emit acoustic energy. Makes sense physically. (Though I find it a bit strange to use mesh heads designed to be silent, and then deliberately hack them to be loud...)

Comment: The reason why I wanted to "add" some volume to the silent heads is so that volume and tones are balanced out when playing along with low volume cymbals. It might not bother anyone else, but it bother me that the low volume cymbals are louder than silent stroke heads. This way i feel the volumen and tone of both drums and cymbals is equal.